# Do Azure websites support https with node.js?

Tags: node.js, azure, https

Azure web role supports https with node.js, but do Azure websites support https?

Answer (score 1):

As of this post : [link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/pl-PL/windowsazurewebsitespreview/thread/0218204f-7be3-4586-bfdb-831cde6b7937) and as far as I'm aware *it's still not possible* to set up a custom SSL certificate at this time for an Azure Website.

If this is part of your requirement I would suggest going for a regular WebRole and setting up a Certificate to be used in the RoleConfiguration.

You can associate a certificate with a WebRole under the EndPoint configuration when the Protocol is set to https shown below:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this should work by default for non-custom domains (foo.azurewebsites.net). As @f0x mentioned, SSL support for *custom* domains isn't available for Windows Azure Web Sites.

Comment: Is this still the case? It seems for standard website subscriptions in Azure now provide SSL on custom sites.

Comment: I believe you're correct that this has changed over the past year.